# Send an array with specific size to workers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mpi

I want to send an array with size of 336 in splitted parts to my 8 workers. I want the workers 0-8 to get the sizes 12,18,30,36,48,54,66 and 72. So add 6 then 12 and 6 and so on... To this point I was able to cut the array into pieces of 10.

This is what I came up with:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

v=np.random.rand(100,1) #array



if rank == 0:

    # Process to send data to the different processes. Just send evenly chunks to the processes.
    for i in range(1, size):

        v_splitted=[np.array_split(v, 10)[i-1]]
        comm.send(v_splitted, dest=i, tag=i)

# worker processes
else:

    # each worker process receives data from master process
    data = comm.recv(source=0, tag=rank)
```

How do I make sure, that each worker gets the desired size?

Comment: What do you need help with? Splitting the array `v`, or sending each worker its workload?

Answer (score 1):

you can use accumulate from itertools and zip to build a list of slices.  Then use that to break down your array in chunks of the desired sizes:

```
from itertools import accumulate
sizes  = [12,18,30,36,48,54,66,72]    # or [*accumulate([12,6]*4)]
breaks = [*accumulate(sizes)]
slices = [slice(s,e) for s,e in zip([0]+breaks,breaks)]

v = list(range(336))
for i,chunk in enumerate(slices):
    print(len(v[chunk]),":",*v[chunk][:3],"...",*v[chunk][-3:])
    # comm.send(v[chunk], dest=i, tag=i)
```

output:

```
12 : 0 1 2 ... 9 10 11
18 : 12 13 14 ... 27 28 29
30 : 30 31 32 ... 57 58 59
36 : 60 61 62 ... 93 94 95
48 : 96 97 98 ... 141 142 143
54 : 144 145 146 ... 195 196 197
66 : 198 199 200 ... 261 262 263
72 : 264 265 266 ... 333 334 335
```

**how it works**

The `breaks` list contains the cumulative numbers of items that are processed at the end of each chunk:

```
[12, 30, 60, 96, 144, 198, 264, 336]
```

These numbers correspond to the end of index ranges that would represent each chunk of data.   To obtain the start of these ranges, we simply need to pair each end value with the end value of the preceding chunk (the first chunk starting at zero):

```
starts (s):   [0] [12, 30, 60,  96, 144, 198, 264, 336]
ends (e):     [12, 30, 60, 96, 144, 198, 264, 336]

ranges:       (0,12), (12,30), (30,60) ... (264,336)
```

This is what the `slices` variable will contain except that, to facilitate usage later on, it returns a list of slice() objects instead of a list of range() objects.  The slice objects can be used directly as subscripts to the list or array containing the data (e.g. `v[slice]`).  The zip() function is used here to create pairs of end values where the previous end (i.e. the start) is obtained by offsetting the breaks with one extra entry (of zero)

Comment: Thank you Alain, one question tho, what does slices = [slice(s,e) for s,e in zip([0]+breaks,breaks)] this line do?